# How to set variable on a session through multiple request

Tags: jsp, session, tomcat, servlets, liferay-7

In my Liferay 7 theme, I want to remember the last page a user clicked on. So, in my theme, I have the following:

```
<#if nav_item.isSelected()>
  ${request.getSession().setAttribute("LAST_ACTIVE",nav_item.getName())}
</#if>
```

In my portlet JSP, I then want to retrieve the value:

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("LAST_ACTIVE")
```

However, I always get a `null` value, probably because the session gets re-created with each request. How do I store the value so that it lasts multiple requests?

Comment: Can you confirm nav_item.getName() is not returning null?

Comment: Yep, I have confirmed that it's not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting my comment to Andre's question to an answer, as per your comment on it:

`${request.getClass().getName()}` in the theme typically reveals a descendant of `HttpServletRequest`, while a portlet is typically using a `PortletRequest` - those are distinct elements (as laid out here with private attributes unless explicitly shared).

In portlet JSPs, be aware that `${request}` is predefined by the *JSP Spec* as `HttpServletRequest` (and thus is often useless in a portlet), while the *Portlet Spec* defines `${renderRequest}`. Make sure to use the right one when in a JSP. In the portlet world, this is typically the later.

Answer (score 1):

Portles (from your mentioned .jsp) might have a private portlet scoped session, which need not to be fully equals with the session of your theme.
You should prepend: `LIFERAY_SHARED_` as prefix to your session attribute.
If this does not work, you can try to add `PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE` when reading and writing session attributes as an additional scope Parameter.

Comment: As an additional explanation and mental model: `${request.getClass().getName()}` in the theme typically reveals a descendant of HttpServletRequest, while a portlet is typically using a PortletRequest - those are distinct elements (as laid out here with private attributes unless explicitly shared). In portlet JSPs, be aware that `${request}` is predefined by the JSP Spec as `HttpServletRequest` (and often useless in a portlet), while the portletSpec defines `${renderRequest}`. Make sure to use the right one when in a JSP.

Comment: @OlafKock That was the problem, never noticed that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you look at the problem from the other side. The session approach is not bad but probably a better way would be to have a filter or a pre-action that would populate a request attribute. The advantage is that with this you set the attribute to the actual change. With the theme session approach, you are always a bit behind.

Comment: My apologies for my late response. Miroslav, do you have any more info on the filter/pre-action approach? Basically, the problem I am solving is that in Liferay, when I click on an article, the article is displayed in a separate page that is hidden in the navbar. As a result, the last clicked nav item should be the one with active css class. My workaround is to include the last nav_item in a session variable and when rendering navbar, I check url for "/-/" and if there's a session variable. If so, I add active class to the last element. I'd love to hear if there's a better/easier solution